# Проблемы с ActionBar

Tags: actionbar, themes, android, java

Начнём с того, что в последнее время перестали работать темы Holo и Holo.Ligth. Затем исчезла иконка приложения в ActionBar-е. Хотя в манифесте всё прописано:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

Везде облазил и ничего путного не нашёл. Помогите мне найти решение. :)

Comment: "Ничто не берётся из ниоткуда и не исчезает в никуда" (с) не помню, кто    
То есть, проблемы беспричинно не появляются. Их причина несомненно в ваших действиях, но пока вы будете скрывать свои действия от нас, мы вам помочь не сможем.

Comment: Я так понял, у тебя Android Studio? 

Я как обновил, с теми же проблемами столкнулся. Более того, какую я тему не пробовал, любая не работает (при запуске программы выдаёт ошибку).

Comment: Я обновляюсь всегда с Carnary Chanel, где выходят самые сырые сборки, и никогда небыло таких проблем.

Comment: У меня Android Studio. И в IntelliJ IDEA пробовал тоже самое. Может в новых версиях Sdk из-за android 5.0 пришлось гугловцам это всё убрать?